# How to check which mouse button was clicked during an MouseClick event in c++/cli?

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli, mouseclick-event, code-translation

It's supposed to work like this in c#, but what's the equivalent in c++/cli?

```
private void CustomControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{        
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
   { 
     ... do something
   } 
}
```

MouseButtons.Right, MouseButtons::Right and MouseButtons->Right all don't seem to compile. It always says

```
error C2039: 'Right' : is not a member of 'System::Enum'
```

Here is my c++/cli code:

```
System::Void WindowTest::pictureBoxTest_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e)
    {
        if (e->Button == MouseButtons::Left)
        {
        // do something
            }
}
```

Comment: Posting C# code is irrelevant... why don't you post the C++/CLI code that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons.aspx) you seem to be missing the `::` before your `MouseButtons::Right`

```
  void panel1_MouseDown( Object^ /*sender*/, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e )
  {
     // Update the mouse path with the mouse information
     Point mouseDownLocation = Point(e->X,e->Y);
     String^ eventString = nullptr;
     switch ( e->Button )
     {
        case ::MouseButtons::Left:
           eventString = "L";
           break;

        case ::MouseButtons::Right:
           eventString = "R";
           break;

        case ::MouseButtons::Middle:
           eventString = "M";
           break;

        case ::MouseButtons::XButton1:
           eventString = "X1";
           break;

        case ::MouseButtons::XButton2:
           eventString = "X2";
           break;

        case ::MouseButtons::None:
        default:
           break;
     }
     if ( eventString != nullptr )
     {
        mousePath->AddString( eventString, FontFamily::GenericSerif, (int)FontStyle::Bold, (float)fontSize, mouseDownLocation, StringFormat::GenericDefault );
     }
     else
     {
        mousePath->AddLine( mouseDownLocation, mouseDownLocation );
     }

     panel1->Focus();
     panel1->Invalidate();
  }
```

Comment: But why? MouseButtons is declared in System.Windows.Forms. Doesn't :: in front mean I want some MouseButtons of the global namespace?

Comment: I can't matking this answer as correct right now. I already tried that. I have to wait 10 min or so ...

Comment: @marc40000 : Yes, that's what that means. If anything, it should be `System::Windows::Forms::` before `MouseButtons`.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would guess its because you have a using for that namespace

Comment: From here I'm guessing that the :: without a namespace means it's implicitly referencing the cli namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d87eee3k(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @mydogisbox : `::` with no preceding identifier always refers to the global namespace. Namespace `cli` is always in scope in C++/CLI, but that's still different from the global namespace. In any case, `MouseButtons` is not in namespace `cli` so I don't see what relevance it would have anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn according to the page I linked `::` is needed when there is a naming conflict between the global namespace and a user-defined symbol.  The using at the top includes whatever namespace into the global namespace.  Something must be conflicting with the `System::Windows::Forms::` namespace so requiring the `::` to specify that the symbol is not local.

Comment: @mydogisbox : Agreed, I'm just noting that that has nothing to do with namespace `cli`. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn fair enough.  I was just making a guess with the first statement.